# How to name call methods with the contents of a string

Tags: java, android, string, android-listview

How do I call a method with the contents of a string? I have say 4 strings:

```
swimming
football
rugby
hockey
```

And I also have 4 methods called:

```
swimming
football
rugby
hockey
```

I have a listview with these strings filling the listview (this is just an example, i actually have a listview with 200 strings) So for the 200 strings, instead of writing an if statement:

```
if(string.equals("Swimming")){swimming();}
```

Can I make it someway that I can have one onclick method that, when an item in the listview was clicked it would run something like:

```
[string]();
```

Where [string] is some code to get what string was chosen from the listview

basically to save myself writing 200 if statements, could i have it so it automatically starts the method named after the string?

Comment: What do your methods do? Are they so different? Can't you make 1 method that take a string parameter and acts accordingly?

Comment: the methods define strings according to what was click, all the strings will be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amended with error handling:

```
try
{
    String string = "swimming";
    MyActivity.class.getMethod(string, null).invoke(this, null);
}
catch(Throwable t)
{
    t.printStackTrace(); // might want to do something else here
}
```

Comment: i don't want to write that out for all 200 odd strings, can i replace the string "swimming" with just string (which is the variable, `String string;` ) Thanks

Comment: eclipse wants me to correct that line to this: `try {
   Mods_info.class.getMethod(wf, null).invoke(this, null);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: Yeah it'll make you handle any error that could occur, but you can make it shorter than that; I'll edit the answer real quick.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection.

```
String type = "swimming";
Method m = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(type, null);
m.invoke(this, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reflection in order to do this.  Rather than type up a full example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) SO post and accepted answer has all the details you will need to implement this.  Note there is overhead to using reflection, and on a mobile device the cost will be greater.  If you could share more details about what you are trying to do there may be a more elegant solution to the larger problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do thad with reflection.
For further info have a look at this post: [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)